# How many 9 character long usernames can be generated with numbers and letters, except a few restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So as an exercise I'm trying to calculate how many 9 character long usernames can be created using the letters A-Z, numbers 0-9 and how many of these contain atleast one 0, but with a few rules / restrictions.

Repetition is allowed.

1. The first character has to be an letter, not an number.
2. The next 4 characters following the first character have to be numbers.
3. The last 4 characters can be either numbers or letters.

L = Letter

N = Number

`[L][N][N][N][N][L/N][L/N][L/N][L/N]`

I'm having trouble understanding how to take these 3 rules into consideration in my calculation.

So far what I've done is separate the username into 3 different calculations, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

1. The first character has to be a letter so 26 possibilities.
2. Four characters that have to be numbers and there are 10 numbers, so $10^{4}$ = 10000
3. 4 characters, either letters or numbers, so $36^{4}$ = 1679616

`26 + 10000 + 1679616 = 1689642` different usernames.

When calculating how many contain at least one zero, I reduced the amount of elements by 1 in steps 2 and 3. Basically trying to calculate `(All combinations)-(Those that contain 1-9)=(Those that have at least one 0)`

1. The first character has to be a letter so 26 possibilities.
2. Four characters that have to be numbers and there are 9 numbers, so $9^{4}$ = 6561
3. 4 characters, either letters or numbers, so $35^{4}$ = 1500625

`26 + 6561 + 1500625 = 1507212`

Then

`1689642 - 1507212 = 182430` usernames that contain at least one 0.

Am I correct? If not, I'd really appreciate any pointers and hints.

Comment: Why did you do 26+10000+1679616? Shouldn’t it be 26x10000x1679616?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between adding and multiplying.  You needed to multiply $26$ with $10^4$ and $36^4$... not add.

Comment: Once you take care of that, your approach is otherwise correct.  Just remember that "*do this THEN that*" you multiply number of options, while "*do this OR that*" is when you add.  There is a bit more nuance which should be covered in any introductory textbook... but in symbols: [rule of product $|A\times B| = |A|\times |B|$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and [rule of sum $|A\sqcup B| = |A|+|B|$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_Principle)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to do two computations, $A$ and $B$.  $A$ will represent the computation when the requirement of at least one $(0)$ is ignored.  $B$ will represent the computation where $(0)$ is not used.  Then, the final computation will be

$$A - B.$$

$$A = 26 \times (10)^4 \times (36)^4.$$

$$B = 26 \times (9)^4 \times (35)^4.$$

So, final computation is

$$26 \times \left\{ ~\left[(10)^4 \times (36)^4\right] - \left[(9)^4 \times (35)^4\right] ~\right\}.$$